# minikube addons configure registry-creds not working for GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, minikube

I followed the [docs](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/) for configuring this and it says it succeeded:

Created a new cluster

```
minikube start -p aged --kubernetes-version=v1.18.10
```

Then setup GCR creds

```
minikube addons configure registry-creds -p aged

Do you want to enable AWS Elastic Container Registry? [y/n]: n

Do you want to enable Google Container Registry? [y/n]: y
-- Enter path to credentials (e.g. /home/user/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json):/Users/meeee/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
-- Do you want to change the GCR URL (Default https://gcr.io)? [y/n]: n

Do you want to enable Docker Registry? [y/n]: n

Do you want to enable Azure Container Registry? [y/n]: n
✅  registry-creds was successfully configured

# enable
minikube addons enable registry-creds -p aged
    ▪ Using image upmcenterprises/registry-creds:1.10
```

but when I deploy I get this error:

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/myproject/myimages/myimage:test": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

While it makes no mention of authenticating to GCR I have also configured `minikube addons enable gcp-auth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the ADC file exist?

```
/home/user/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json):/Users/meeee/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

If not you'll need to [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) beforehand.

And, assuming the mechanism creates a Secret in your Namespace, you'll still need to use `imagePullSecrets`.

This approach is hacky and you would be better placed creating a Service Account specifically for the GCR access.

Using your user account as a service account this way, shares all your user account's permissions  when all that's needed is `role/storage.admin` to pull from GCR. Additionally user accounts are likely bound to multiple projects whereas the account only needs access to the specific project (better yet bucket).

Comment: yes the file exists if its not there it throws an error

Comment: If its meant to be used with `imagePullSecrets` it makes no mention of what the secret it creates is named to reference in the pod spec

Comment: The documentation suggests that it creates a Secret when it says "which maps credentials into minikube to support pulling from Google Container Registry (GCR),...". Try `kubectl get secrets --all-namesdpaces` (though it probably uses the Default Namespace) and eyeball the names. I've not used minikube but I've used GCR with GKE and other managed Kubernetes offerings and MicroK8s. The Docker credentials are mapped into a Secret and then the Secret is referenced by `imagePullSecrets` on e.g. Deployments

Comment: I see it, looks like it creates a secret named `gcr-secret`. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Great. You'll need to duplicate that Secret in any Namespaces you use for Deployments but, otherwise you should be good to go!

Comment: The plugin already propagates the secret to all namespaces it seems.